# jQuery Datatables ul and li format

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am new in the jQuery datable plugin. I have implemented some datatables in the 'tr' 'td' format. But my requirement is to implement the records in the 'ul' and 'li' list format.
Currently I have datatables where the records are showing in the in normal table format where each row containing one record. But my desired output is some thing like in the list format
like:

```
<ul>

<li>
<div class="grid-picto user">
<small>Administrator</small>
<p class="grid-name">Test Uset1</p>
<p class="grid-details">Age: <b>28</b><br>
Gender: <b>male</b><br>
Country: <b>USA</b></p>
</div>
<ul class="grid-actions">
<li><a href="#" title="Edit" class="with-tip"><img src="pencil.png" width="16" height="16"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="Delete" class="with-tip"><img src="cross-circle.png" width="16" height="16"></a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li>
<div class="grid-picto user">
<small>Administrator</small>
<p class="grid-name">Test Uset2</p>
<p class="grid-details">Age: <b>28</b><br>
Gender: <b>male</b><br>
Country: <b>USA</b></p>
</div>
<ul class="grid-actions">
<li><a href="#" title="Edit" class="with-tip"><img src="/admin/assets/images/icons/fugue/pencil.png" width="16" height="16"></a></li>
<li><a href="#" title="Delete" class="with-tip"><img src="/admin/assets/images/icons/fugue/cross-circle.png" width="16" height="16"></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: is this a troll post? you want to use dataTABLES to output lists?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the jQuery dataTable plugin to display the records, but in a list view.

Answer (score 0):

For example use function php str_replace() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php